# Hsmartwindow doesnt show image in .net program on production pc

Tags: halcon

My first stack overflow question, here we go.
Last week the computer on which a prototype vision application written in C#/.net was running crashed due to an unreleated reason. this resulted in the need to fresh install windows (windows 10 IOT). after installing windows, halcon 20.11 progress and setting the licenses the application starts, but no output is shown on the smart window control, even tho this worked beforehand?

i have been trying to debug this problem for the last day, but have had no luck, what i have allready tried:

- used the remote debugging toe verify that the image is captured and processed and "displayed".
- checked the system logs for any warnings, there were none.
- Tried one of the example programs the come with Halcon, which also does **not **work.
- Ran the application on my development PC, which worked flawlessly as it always did.
- Reinstalling Halcon.

does anyone have had any similar experiences and/or any clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

problem has been solved. in the end a reset of the bios settings to there default values did the trick. Don't know what they exact cooperative was, but at least it works once again.